# Is Application url is required for submitting App to App store

Tags: macos, app-store

Just I need some clarification whether Application url is required or not for submitting App to App store.If I dont have url for the applicationan,cant I upload the app to app store?

Answer (score 2):

i am not really sure, still not found any information if application URL is optional or not, but maybe this checklist could help:
http://www.slideshare.net/appsolutegenius/iphone-app-store-submission-process

Comment: This is not giving answer to my question,Any way thanks for sharing good link,vote up.